# Bokeh choropleth plot does not change with slider

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, choropleth

Would like to create a bokeh choropleth for my own use. It shows China split into it's `Provinces` by polygons, colored by a value called `surplus`. I have `Years` from 1995 to 2016, and am trying to make the colours update along with a slider. My dataframe looks something like this (random sample of 10):

```
     Year   Province       Surplus
371  2014      Hubei  5.953000e+06
268  1999     Fujian  7.123000e+06
44   1995      Hebei  9.030000e+05
246  1999      Anhui  1.300600e+07
236  2011   Zhejiang -5.258105e+06
406  2005  Guangdong  1.117000e+07
180  1999   Shanghai  1.543000e+06
252  2005      Anhui  1.250800e+07
346  2011      Henan -1.538884e+05
399  1998  Guangdong  1.614100e+07
```

My code is as such:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data = df_all)

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = Spectral6, 
                                 low = df_all.Surplus.min(),
                                 high = df_all.Surplus.max())

p = figure(title = 'Statistics by Year',
           plot_height = 700,
           plot_width = 1100)

p.patches('x', 'y', 
          source = source, 
          fill_color = {'field': 'Surplus', 
                        'transform': color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black',
          line_width = 0.60,    
          fill_alpha = 0.60)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    new_data = df_all[df_all.Year == yr]
    source.data = new_data

slider = Slider(start = 1995, 
                end = 2016, 
                value = 1995, step = 1, 
                title = "Year")
slider.on_change('value', callback)

hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Province','@Province'), ('Surplus', '@Surplus')])

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper = color_mapper, width=8,  location=(0,0))
layout = column(widgetbox(slider), p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)

outfp = r"C:\Users\myname\surplus2016.html"
save(p, outfp)
```

However, my colors don't shift with my slider and I have no idea why yet. Probably something with my update step. Any ideas? I've managed to get the choropleth out though.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code as a "regular" python script with `show` you are creating a standalone HTML output that only exists in the browser, with no connection to any Python process. It's not possible to run real Python callbacks in this situation, because a browser knows nothing about Python at all. Running real Python code in callbacks, i.e. with `on_change` requires running the code as a [Bokeh server application](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html):

- replace the `show` call with `curdoc().add_root(p)`, and
- run the code with `bokeh serve --show <filename>`

Comment: Sorry about this, i think i'm not really that sure about how this works. I usually save it to a HTML file which as you said, won't move as expected. I changed my save command to ```outfp = r"C:\Users\myname\surplus2016.ipynb"``` and added in the line for curdoc, then ran the bokeh serve code in my anaconda prompt. I received an error saying Notebook does not appear to be JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: There should not be a `save` call at all. You need to run `bokeh serve` on the actual script you have above.

Comment: I see... it opened in my browser and I got a blank screen though.. any idea why this is happening? Ask me anything and I'll provide it

Comment: Did you add the call to `curdoc().add_root` at the end? There are lots of examples you can study (and run yourself) here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app

Comment: Yes I did. This is rather confusing but I think I'll check out your link and egs before attempting it again. Thanks. Was in quite a rush to plot for work.